# I want to duplicate a random letter of a string 1 time. How can I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, duplicates

This is my string:

```
keyword = "qatarworldcup"
```

I mean my string should be `qqatarworldcup`, `qatarworldcupp` or `qatarrworlddcup`

Comment: `"qatarwordcup"`-- did you mean for this to be `"qatarworldcup"`?

Comment: Do you want to duplicate _all instances_ of the selected character, or only one?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I want a random character to be duplicated once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iteration through index-character pairs, apply the condition on each "term" with the *ternary operator* and join everything together.

```
import random

# fix random number generator (for testing only!)
random.seed(190)

keyword = "qatarworldcup"

# random index
r = random.randint(0, len(keyword)-1)
out = ''.join(char * 2 if i == r else char for i, char in enumerate(keyword))

print(out)
#qaatarworldcup
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty easy to do if you break it up into parts.

1. Select a random letter from the word.

```
import random
letter_index = random.randint(0, len(keyword)-1)
```

2. Split the word into two parts at the letter you picked.

```
before, after = keyword[:letter_index], keyword[letter_index:]
```

3. Join the two parts, adding an extra instance of the selected letter

```
result = before + keyword[letter_index] + after
```

If your strings are big enough, or you're doing this multiple times, you could see a speedup from reducing the number of string concatenations, because that's an O(N) operation on account of the immutability of strings. Since the selected letter already exists in the word, you can split it such that the selected letter is the last character of `before` and the first character of `after`. Then, you only need a single concatenation<sup>Thanks to [@Mechanic Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17980931/mechanic-pig) for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73053340/i-want-to-duplicate-a-random-letter-of-a-string-1-time-how-can-i-do/73053431#comment129024894_73053431)</sup>:

```
before, after = keyword[:letter_index+1], keyword[letter_index:]
result = before + after
```

Comment: `>>> s = "abcdef"
>>> import random
>>> i = random.randrange(0, len(s))
>>> i
2
>>> s[:i] + s[i] + s[i] + s[i+1::1]
'abccdef'`

Comment: `keyword[:letter_index + 1] + keyword[letter_index:]` only needs to be concatenate once

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint
keyword = "qatarwordcup"
idx = randint(0, len(keyword) - 1)
keyword = keyword[:idx] + keyword[idx] + keyword[idx:]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this

```
import random

#Find random position in string
r = random.randint(0, len(keyword) - 1)
#Create new string with added character at random position
newStr = keyword[:r] + keyword[r] + keyword[r:]
```